# How to order by enum on grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to order by enum but I'm getting some errors on that...

THis is the code i'm using:

```
 and {
      invoiceTicketDetail {
         order('date', 'asc')
         order('code', 'asc')
      }
}
lineType {
   order('sortOrder', 'asc')
}
```

The lineType is an Enum and there is an int attribute named sortOrder, to order the lineType properly..
The problem is that I'm getting the following error when I try to execute this

```
No signature of method: InvoiceService.lineType() is applicable for argument types: (InvoiceService$_tt__getInvoiceDetailList_closure36_closure57) values: [InvoiceService$_tt__getInvoiceDetailList_closure36_closure57@3c7c8544]
Possible solutions: asType(java.lang.Class), asType(java.lang.Class). Stacktrace follows:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: InvoiceService.lineType() is applicable for argument types: (InvoiceService$_tt__getInvoiceDetailList_closure36_closure57) values: [InvoiceService$_tt__getInvoiceDetailList_closure36_closure57@3c7c8544]
Possible solutions: asType(java.lang.Class), asType(java.lang.Class)
    at InvoiceService$_$tt__getInvoiceDetailList_closure36$$EPQTbhPk.doCall(InvoiceService.groovy:477)
```

InvoiceService is the service I'm using, but it's not the main object. If I just remove the lineType lines it works fine, but I need to add this lineType in this ordenation.

Is there any other way to sort it by complex object multiple columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort by the `lineType.sortOrder` because GORM/Hibernate sorts by a domain/entity property. It ends up being a database column, but you can't specify a database column with sort(). `lineType` is a domain property but `lineType.sortOrder` is not, (it's an enum property). Sorting by `lineType` will sort by the enum's ordinal value. That's what you'll see stored in the database.

## Sort by a SQLProjection

The most complicated way (hint, probably not worth it) is to create a [Hibernate User Type](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#customHibernateTypes) for the enum so that you can store the sorting value in a separate database column. With such a column, then you can use a SQLProjection to dynamically create a property and sort by it. One down side of this approach is that you won't be able to return instances of the root entity (ex. the SomeDomain in SomeDomain.withCriteria()). Instead you can return instance IDs:

```
def ids = DomainClass.withCriteria {
    and {
          invoiceTicketDetail {
             order('date', 'asc')
             order('code', 'asc')
          }
    }

    projections {
        property('id')
        sqlProjection 'the_added_column as sortOrder', 'sortOrder', org.hibernate.type.IntegerType as org.hibernate.type.Type
    }

    sort('sortOrder')
}
```

## Add a new domain property

You can add a new property (ex. sortOrder) directly to the domain class.

## Groovy

You can sort on the client-side in Groovy.

```
DomainClass.withCriteria {
    and {
          invoiceTicketDetail {
             order('date', 'asc')
             order('code', 'asc')
          }
    }
}.toSorted { it.lineType.sortOrder }
```

Comment: Emmanuel Rosa, I couldn't understand the first approach... I tried the third one, but didn't work... The second one is not possible for me... the model will get wrong because sortOrder is not part of the solution for this problem... Seems that the first one is the best way to do it... but I couldn't understand what should I use in place where you add "the_added_column as sortOrder".

Comment: First you need to create a Hibernate User Type to correspond to the lineType enum. Then in Grails you can map to table columns to the lineType: the one you already have for the ordinal, and a new one for the sort order. Then you can use the new column in the sqlprojection (ex. the_added_column). Basically the sqlprojection dynamically creates a property out of the added column so that you can sort by it. https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#customHibernateTypes